# Building a SaaS application in CodeIgniter like Shopify with custom domain alias

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, saas

I am working on a SaaS application. We take **Shopify / Magento** Go etc as reference.

- I used CodeIgniter PHP framework.
- SaaS Methodology - Multiple database, single code-base

Our SaaS architecture is as follows:

[image: SaaS Architecture]

- when a customer signup a database is build with his name and contain his specific databases.
- when a customer signup he get a sub-domain (Ex: test1.example.com)
- The customer can add his own domain that points to the system defined sub-domain. (Ex: test1.example.com to www.mydomain.com )

How to achieve this functionality?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: achieve the described functionality

Comment: Far too broad for this sites (and most others, come to think of it), but: design your database first, so it is multi-tenant. Design your software so it can be re-themed, i.e. using an MVC-like framework which can load different layouts/stylesheets. Add a URL field so you can do internal routing based on the domain. Get your web server to catch all subdomains and route them to the same vhost. Bear in mind this is not a trivial undertaking.

Comment: Is there any reference or tutorial or blog to achieve same what I asked?

Comment: No, there isn't. You are looking to develop a complex product, and so either need to acquire the skills to create this (takes years) or hire someone who can layout a broad design for you to work within, so that less experienced programmers can fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to go through few configuration options.

1. Configure DNS: Create sub-domain with *. (ask you host)
2. You have to configure apache or .htaccess to point all requests coming to your domain point to same directory.
3. Database Setting: Try to learn how to use multiple database in codeigniter.

That's all. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should look for the term: " codeigniter multi Tennant app " and as said before, managing too many database isn't a solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can achive proposed SAAS application this way,

There will be 1 database for application itself, and another N number of databases for clients, each new client will have new database.

- Allow signup to your clients by asking basic details + subdomain to choose like blogspot do, subdomains taken by existing clients wont be allowed to reuse
- When client signup successfully, one separate DB will be created and they will landed to their dashboard. Here one DB server will be fine but should have enough space and other parameter set to handle multiple databases.
- Now dahsboard onwards, user will able to see list of functionality to use along with some predefined set of content that will be shared between user and loaded from "app DB". Whatever they do add will goes to their own independent DB
- Here codebase will be deployed at one code server and main domain will be mapped to that so login/singup etc will be happen here and user's identification will happen at login level.

**App DB:** This DB will be responsible to store app level master data, i.e. Client's profile + login details, other admin related stuff which they meant to share to their clients. In case of shopify kind of app, themes, layout, templates can be master stuff that will store into this DB.

**User DB:** Only user's created, added content and its sub content should be stored. Whatever we can call user's ownership should be stored here.

**Note**: If its paid service, then you can use good payment gateway like stripe or chargebee to manage all your plans, subscriptions, email notification, dunning, payments log, payment success/failure, payment invoices.

WRT to subdomain and custom domain concept, you can do this using virtual hosting mechanism, you can do with apache as well as nginx server.
- Subdomain: Create config files as per server, put on proper place and any created subdomain will bind to particular pysical virtual directory
- Customdomain: Can create physical directory same as subdomain along with config files but in this case, you will need to ask your client to do DNS binding with our IP addess

In both this case when request comes to our server, server will check if config file and physical directory available tp hit then it will redirect user to destiny forlder.

Comment: If you want to see how practically we can do subdomain + custom domain binding/mapping with physical directory then contact me, its long process and took month to develop as not much straigh forward help available over internet. We have added free SSL too for our all client's subdomain and even  custom domains.